# Reading NSDictionary of JSON data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I have JSON data:

```
{"data":[
     {"userID":"1", "username":"name1"},
     {"userID":"2", "username":"name2"},
     {"userID":"3", "username":"name3"}
]}
```

returned into an NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonReturnData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

The jsonObject looks like this:

[image]

How do I then read the values in the NSDictionary? I have:

```
NSDictionary *dictItem1 = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
```

which reads the data item but how do get the values?

Comment: The JSON you gave doesn't reflect the screenshot you put. It's a `NSArray` at top level, not a `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it reading the data into an NSArray:

```
NSArray *JsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonReturnData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
NSArray *array = [JsonData objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *dictItem = (NSDictionary *)array;
NSArray *arrayItems = [dictItem objectForKey:@"data"];
```

The arrayItems then held each of the records.

As pointed out it be further simplified with:

```
NSArray *JsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonReturnData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
NSDictionary *dictItem = (NSDictionary *)[JsonData objectAtIndex:0];;
NSArray *arrayItems = [dictItem objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Comment: `NSDictionary *dictItem = (NSDictionary *)array;`? What? That doesn't make sense AT ALL. Just do `NSDictionary *dictItem = `(NSDictionary *)[slidersJsonData objectAtIndex:0];`.

Comment: Also, no need for `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`.

Comment: @Larme Your first comment is exactly what I have done, but just you have simplified it as shown int the edit. Is that right? I have tried each of the NSJSONReadingOptions and they all work. What would you suggest - NSJSONReadingMutableContainers?

Comment: The comment was about you are naming it array, but it’s not an array ! It’s a dictionary ! It’s like naming a cow a dog. For the option, use nilOption.

Comment: I agree the naming it 'array' was not sensible but it is an array. If I set it as an NSDictionary I get an error as you can't objectAtIndex in dictionary. Also I can't have nil as an option without a warning. Anyway it is working perfectly - thanks for checking.